# Storing twitter stream in csv

Tags: python-2.7, csv, twitter

```
def SentimentAnalysis(text):
    return text

class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self,data):
        #print data
        tweet = data.split('"text"')[1].split('"')[1]
        created_date = data.split('"created_at"')[1].split('"')[1]
        profile_stats = data.split('"verified":false,')
                        [1].split('"created_at"')[0]
        print 'TWEET = ', tweet
        print 'Created = ', created_date
        print 'Profile_Stats = ', profile_stats
        return True

    def on_error(self,status):
        print status
```

I am using tweepy to get a stream of tweets. How do i store what i am printing in a csv file? Any help would be great.

Comment: You might want to take a look to [NLTK twitter howto](http://www.nltk.org/howto/twitter.html), which have functions to write to csv.

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses the csv module, so you have to import it at the beginning of you script.
You should also call `csv_file.close()` after having collected your data.

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self,data):
        #print data
        tweet = data.split('"text"')[1].split('"')[1]
        created_date = data.split('"created_at"')[1].split('"')[1]
        profile_stats = data.split('"verified":false,')
                        [1].split('"created_at"')[0]
        print 'TWEET = ', tweet
        print 'Created = ', created_date
        print 'Profile_Stats = ', profile_stats
        c.writerow([tweet, created_date, profile_stats])
        return True

    def on_error(self,status):
        print status

csv_file = open("twitter.csv", "wb")
c = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ';')
```

You should probably use the JSON module as well in order to extract your data from the response.

[The following Tutorial](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/) may be interesting for you.

Comment: your code works fine but gives following error all of a sudden:  profile_stats = data.split('"verified":false,')[1].split('"created_at"')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range